# Information display systems Implementation

Tags: multiple-monitors, raspberry-pi, remote-control

We want to implement multiple display systems at various places in our organization to show information and this information is for display purpose only. We dont know how to start.

At first, we thought that, Using a large monitors+[raspberry-pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) is a best solution. But then, we need to find the software for displaying the information in full screen nearly all the day.

So, our requirements are:

1. The display systems should be remotely monitored for updating the content.
2. We may display different information at different display systems.
3. We have to display images/videos, sometimes we may display them with audio.
4. We have to display scrolling text whenever required.

We have searched in google for this, but dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep this simple, I'd just setup a webserver anywhere the Pi can access. Then setup the Pi to run a browser full screen on start up pointing to that location. It should be very simple. The fact that on the other end you have a full featured webserver makes maintenance a breeze. Throw SSH on the Pi for sure. Also, if you are a GUI user, throw on VPN or [rdesktop](http://elinux.org/RPi_XRDP_Server):

```
# Only run ONE of the following two lines:
# yum install xrdp -y # Redhat based
# apt-get install xrdp # Debian based

# chkconfig --levels 35 xrdp on
# service xrdp start
```

While checking my facts for this I ran across a good tutorial on using [matchbox as a browser kiosk on the Pi](http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-boot-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-fullscreen-browser-kiosk/). If this is too easy, then you can make it much more fun by using only X and nothing else. If this is what you want to do then I suspect you already know how though.